# 2 Young adult fantasy books read in the 1980's. A socially awkward boy transported to another world possibly by a magic carpet in first book.

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read these two books in the 80's so they could have been written much earlier.  The boy befriends creatures and must fight a sorcerer or sorceress that lives in an underwater fortress.I seem to remember it had a frozen underwater maze.  In the second book, it involves a Djinn in the shape of a serpent who guards a hoard of gold and treasure.  The title might have Djinn in it. The second book might have a girl that goes with him.
I seem to remember that the author was British - "Sir" something.  The books had a very Narnia like feel and were very lengthy.
The cover really stood out to me - it was a double cover that had a small cutout oval and when you opened it, it revealed all the characters in the book.

Comment: You might try http://www.isfdb.org - searching for Name "Sir" produced a list of several dozen authors, one of which might ring a bell.